# Uninstalling MATLAB from laptop, how to get rid of launcher icon?

Tags: uninstall, launcher, icons

I messed up my MATLAB install... Followed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB/R2010a but launcher isn't working.  It says "Could not launch 'MATLAB R2010a' Failed to execute child process "matlab" (No such file or directory).  Probably messed up the place where I downloaded it.

I want to start off with a clean slate.. I removed all of the files installed, but am left with the launcher icon created using these instructions:
Create A MATLAB Launcher

1. Get an icon:

   > sudo wget http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/21/Matlab_Logo.png -O /usr/share/icons/matlab.png
2. Get the launcher file:

   > sudo wget 'https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MATLAB?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=matlab-r2010a.desktop' -O /usr/share/applications/matlab.desktop

How do I remove this launcher icon???

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't going to `/usr/share/icons` and deleting `matlab.png` and going to `usr/share/applications/` and deleting `matlab.desktop` work?